# Cannot see OpenLayers under Plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Although I have installed the OpenLayers plugin in QGIS 2.4, I cannot see it in the list when I click on Plugins.

Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Thanks the question with the answers have really helped me. I kept wondering why I couldn't find the openlayers pluggin.

Answer (score 9):

Unlike previous versions, the OpenLayers plugin now resides in the <kbd>web</kbd> menu:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since QGIS 2.4, it is in the "Web" submenu.

It was a kind of design decision to move the plugins from the `plugin` submenu to `Raster`/`Vector`/`Web` submenus.

If you updated from QGIS 2.2 you have to update the Plugin too.

If you have another installation of QGIS 2.2 in a different folder, you have to reactivate the plugin in QGIS 2.4 after each running of QGIS 2.2, because the latest version is not compatible to QGIS 2.2 or older.

Comment: I don't see it in the Web sub menu either.

Comment: @NWTAdam Look under "installed" plugins if it is there, but unchecked. Sometimes it gets deactivated.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. You would think having it checked would be default after installation.

Answer (score 1):

For my QGIS 2.4 this is located in:

Web > OpenLayers plugin

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on QGIS 2.14.3, but the issue was because I was connected to the enterprise VPN network which has a framework preventing the download to all of these so the plugin manager window was not showing any of the important plugin in the list. Once I disconnected from the Enterprise VPN, I started to see these important plugin in the manager menu.