# OSM in Qgis 2.8

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

The plugin 'OpenLayers plugins' doesn't work any more in Qgis version 2.8 'Wien'.

Is there another solution to load/ add an open street map file?

Comment: It still works for me. Do you get an error message, or do you miss it in the menu? Take a look under `installed plugins`, it might have been deactivated.

Comment: openlayers is under the web menu now.

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110253/cannot-see-openlayers-under-plugin-in-qgis-2-4